# Global convergence with Newton method for nonlinear systems

Tags: convergence-divergence, newton-raphson

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a function for which we seek a fixed point,
$$f:(x,y)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}
-5x+2\sin x+2\cos y\\
-5y+2\sin y+2\cos x
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I made a python program to solve this with the Newton's method $$X_{k+1}=X_k-(J_{X_k}f)^{-1}f(X_k)$$ and it worked with a random $x_0$ (so there maybe is global convergence).
How can I prove that in this case the Newton's method is globally convergent (or not) ?

Comment: You have $X_{k+1} = \phi(X_k)$ so it is sufficient to show that $||\phi|| < 1$ in  $\mathcal{R}^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to Cesarea I was able to visualize the answer to my question (to calculate $||\phi ||$ was not really interesting by hand), and there is indeed a global convergence.